# url launcher not working on physical device

Tags: flutter, dart, url, android-emulator

i have a problem with Url launcher in flutter. in emulator both in debug and release the Url launcher works in directs the user to the Url but  on physical device both in debug and release it does not work , this is my android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bazi_bistchel">
<!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
     the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: What's the Android version of your emulator and physical device?

Comment: emulator android 9 physical device android 13

Answer (score 0):

Starting on Android 11 (API 30), you have to add any URL schemes passed to `canLaunchUrl` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, otherwise it won't work.

From the [package's configuration instruction for Android](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android):

> Add any URL schemes passed to `canLaunchUrl` as `<queries>` entries in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, otherwise it will return false in most cases starting on Android 11 (API 30) or higher. A `<queries>` element must be added to your manifest as a child of the root element.

For example, if you want to be able to launch a https URL scheme, you can include the following `<intent>` element as part of the `<queries>` element in your manifest:

```xml
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
<queries>
```